# Lower bound for $\frac{\sum_{i,j}\min((f_i-f_j)^2,(g_i-g_j)^2)}{\sum_{i,j}\max((f_i-f_j)^2,(g_i-g_j)^2)}$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, special-functions

Let $f\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $g\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be two orthogonal unit vectors such that $\sum_{i}{f_i}=\sum_{i}{g_i}=0$.

> **Question.** Can we prove this?
>   $$\frac{\sum_{\{i,j\}}\min((f_i-f_j)^2,(g_i-g_j)^2)}{\sum_{\{i,j\}}\max((f_i-f_j)^2,(g_i-g_j)^2)} \ge \frac{1}{2n-1}$$

Comment: Just a thought.  Unit vectors summing to 0 satisfy $\sum_{i,j} (f_i - f_j)^2 = 2n$, so your claim is equivalent to showing $\sum_{i,j} \max( (f_i - f_j)^2, (g_i - g_j)^2) \leq 2(2n-1)$.  Do you have any examples with this bound being tight?

Comment: @PatDevlin: In addition to the Amdeberhan example, there are many other tight examples.

Comment: Where did this question come from?

Comment: This has relation with my another question in [http://mathoverflow.net/questions/259865/the-expectation-of-two-sides-of-rectangle-is-equal-can-we-deduce-that-in-the-ex].

Comment: Oh, yes.  [I liked that question too]

Comment: An equivalent statement is $\sum_{i,j}|(f_i-f_j)(g_i-g_j)|\le 2n-2$, in the same assumptions on $f$, $g$. Note that Cauchy-Schwarz almost does it: $\sum_{i,j}|(f_i-f_j)(g_i-g_j)|\le 2n$

Comment: @PietroMajer: It's not clear to me why these two are equivalent. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: 1) Use $2\max(a,b)=a+b+|a-b|$ and  $2\min(a,b)=a+b-|a-b|$ in any $\max$ and $\min$ ; 2) Replace $(f,g)$ with $({f+g \over {\sqrt 2}},{f-g\over {\sqrt 2}})$: this is a bijection of the minimization domain  into itself.

Comment: @PietroMajer: A Genius Comment. thank you very much. Can u give me a reference for your last point?

Comment: About  $(f,g)\mapsto(f',g'):=({f+g\over \sqrt{2}},  {f-g\over \sqrt{2}})$: one just notes it is an involution of the set described in the first line of the OP.

Comment: @PietroMajer: Dear Pietro, I am novice in math and still have a problem in understanding your last comment. can you please explain it a little more?

Comment: Consider the set $S$ of pairs $(f,g)$ you described in the first line. Then $(f',g')$ described above is still in this set, and the transformed pairs $(f',g')$ will give all elements of $S$. Therefore minimizing over  $(f,g)$ or over $(f',g')$ is equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

The example below shows that the bounds are tight.

Take the vectors $v=[1,2,\dots,(n-2),-\binom{n-1}2,0]$ and $w=[-1,-1,\dots,-1,(n-1)]$, then normalize them, with $\Vert v\Vert^2=\frac{3n-5}2\binom{n}3$ and $\Vert w\Vert^2=n(n-1)$, to get
$$f=\frac{v}{\Vert v\Vert}\qquad \text{and} \qquad
g=\frac{w}{\Vert w\Vert}.$$
Then, $\sum_{i,j}\max_{i,j}\{(f_i-f_j)^2,(g_i-g_j)^2\}$ equals
\begin{align} 2\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n-2}\frac{(i-j)^2}{\Vert v\Vert^2}+
2\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}\frac{(i+\binom{n-1}2)^2}{\Vert v\Vert^2}+2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{n^2}{\Vert w\Vert^2}=2(2n-1).
\end{align}